# Is there a better way to get dd-wrt to ignore my ISP's 3rd DNS server?

Tags: dns, dhcp, dd-wrt

My ISP's DHCP server specifies 3 DNS servers that provide ads on mistyped domain names. I'm using a third party DNS provider that only has 2 DNS servers, but unless I put something in the third box dd-wrt fills it with the ISP's 3rd crappy DNS server and mistyped domain names go to their ad page.

I've used an unused IP address on the LAN. Is this the best solution?

Comment: just add one of the google dns servers, or 4.2.2.2 :)

Comment: This looks like a bug in DD-WRT.  It shouldn't use DNS servers from DHCP at all if they're manually overridden.  [Report it to them](http://www.dd-wrt.com/bugtracker/) and they might fix it.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would probably be to pick a second third-party DNS provider so that your DNS will still work if the first one is unavailable.

Using an unused IP address works, but if you request a non-existent domain name and the first two servers don't respond, you'll need to wait for the third request to time out before getting the "this domain doesn't seem to exist" response.

Answer (score 0):

Enter the same DNS twice? Or use another 3rd party DNS service like OpenDNS?

Comment: It ignores the duplicate entry.